# Select a Treeview node given the binded object of the node

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a WPF Treeview binded to an ObservableCollection. I need to select a node of this Treeview based on the binded value on the node.

Let's say the Treeview looks like this:

```
ROOT
  NODE 1: object A
  NODE 2: object B
    NODE 2.1: object C
    NODE 2.2: object D
  NODE 3: object E
    NODE 3.1: object F
      NODE 3.1.1: object G
```

If I have an instance of 'object C' how do I expand and select the node 2.1 on my Treeview?

-UPDATE-

Tried to use:

treeview.SelectedItem = object C

But it says the property is read only.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Could you elaborate more without going straight to the mechanics of it?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Post more code. Also, nothing that a `SelectMany()` can't deal with....

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't very clear. I just reformulated the entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if anyone is interested in future, I used:

```
treeview.SelectedItem = object C;
```

To be able to do that I used the extension method provided here:

http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/